# Pythonic way to split project into modules?

Tags: python

Say, there is a module `a` which, among all other stuff, exposes some submodule `a.b`.
AFAICS, it is desired to maintain modules in such a fashion that one types `import a`, `import a.b` and then invokes something `b`-specific in a following way: `a.b.b_specific_function()` or `a.a_specific_function()`.

The questions I'd like to ask is how to achive such effect?
There is **directory** `a` and there is source-code file `a.py` inside of it. Seems to be logical choice, thought it would look like `import a.a` then, rather than `import a`. The only way I see is to put `a.py`'s code to the `__init__.py` in the `a` directory, thought it is definitely wrong...

So how do I keep my namespaces clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code into `__init__.py`. There is nothing wrong with this for a small subpackage. If the code grows large it is also common to have a submodule with a repeated name like `a/a.py` and then inside `__init__.py` import it using `from .a import *`.

Comment: And what do I do, if `a` has became so huge that there is `a/a.py`, `a/_utils.py`, `a/_more_stuff.py`?

Comment: Import into `a/__init__.py` everything you need to be accessible from other modules when using `import a`. So for example `from ._utils import *`.